# Print boolean result in one line

Tags: boolean

Is there a way in java to print the answer of a boolean (true/false) in just one printline? So not via an if-statement etc. If so what would the print statement look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag = true;
System.out.println(flag != false?true:false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(booleanResult);
```